# 'No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'' error in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

when trying to use OpenCv as a layer in AWS Lambda function, I get the below error:

```
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': \n\nIMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!\n\nImporting the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for\nmany reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was\ninstalled.\n\nWe have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:\n\n    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html\n\nPlease note and check the following:\n\n  * The Python version is: Python3.7 from \"/var/lang/bin/python3.7\"\n  * The NumPy version is: \"1.21.6\"\n\nand make sure that they are the versions you expect.\nPlease carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.\n\nOriginal error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'\n",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Could anyone please help.

Comment: You need to provide more detail about how you have packaged the layer and what binaries you have downloaded.  Have you read this? -> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/